# Cross (sub)domain ajax form submit with captcha

Tags: php, ajax, session, cross-domain, captcha

I'm running into the following problem. A frontend website (www.domain.com) is used to fill in a form that belongs to the backend (backend.domain.com). This form is protected with a captcha, and the reference value for the captcha is saved in the user session (in PHP).

The submission should be Ajax based, which gives some problems with the cross domains. Therefore a wrote a little PHP proxy on www.domain.com. This proxy requests the form of the backend. When the user submits the form, an Ajax request is made to the proxy and the proxy sends a validation request to the backend and returns the result.

All of this works quite well, except for the captcha that saves the references in the user session. Since the frontend website submits the form to the backend, the backend will use a session for the frontend.

What would be the best way to fix this? I've came up with 2 methods. The first would be to include the reference of the captcha in the form (hashed), so that no sessions are needed. The other way would be to include the form directly from the backend, using an iframe. This second method will probably work fine, but it feels really ugly. What would you suggest for  a situation like this?

Update: a sequence diagram describing the situation:

```
Client                  www.domain.com   backend.domain.com
  |                            |                   |
  |-------visit site---------->|                   |
  |                            |-----get form----->|
  |                            |<----return form---|
  |<------return form----------|                   |
  |                            |                   |
  |-------submit form--------->|                   |
  |                            |-----submit form-->|
  |                            |<----send reply----|
  |<------captcha failed-------|                   |
  v                            v                   v
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like a cookie (or session number) problem. The cookie set for the session is valid for the www site, but not for the backend site. But since all of the communication goes via your front-end, could you not use the front-end site to do the authorisation?

```
Client                  www.domain.com   backend.domain.com
  |                            |                   |
  |-------visit site---------->|                   |
  |                            |--get login form-->|
  |                            |<----return form---|
  |                            |set cookie         |
  |<-return login form+cookie--|                   |
  |                            |                   |
  |----submit login form------>|                   |
  |                            |-----submit form-->|
  |                            |                   |check cookie
  |                            |<----send reply----|
  |<------captcha failed-------|                   |
  v                            v                   v
```

The www site must be setting the cookie since it's communicating with the client, but the backend checks it - as the cookie is set for a different domain, backend can't access it. Solution: www should read the cookie and forward the cookie data to backend for processing.

Comment: The sequence diagram is not exactly right, I've updated my question with a sequence diagram describing the situation. But you are right that this is a cookie/session number problem.

Comment: @Intru Updated answer, hopefully getting somewhere.